# Simple query not working under Anorm 2.4-M1

Tags: scala, anorm

The code is very simple, I dont know why it is not working.

```scala
 DB.withConnection(implicit connection => {

    val count: Long = SQL("select count(*) from Country").as(scalar[Long].single)
     println(count)
 })
```

The error message is `"java.sql.SQLException: Invalid operation for forward only resultset : isLast"`

The library using in **build.sbt**:

```scala
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" % "anorm_2.10" % "2.4.0-M1"

libraryDependencies += "commons-dbcp" % "commons-dbcp" % "1.4"

libraryDependencies += "com.oracle" % "ojdbc14" % "11.1.0.7"
```

It is working fine under Anorm 2.1, but I dont know why 2.4 throw this exception

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Anorm 2.4 is not final release (as milestone 1), so issue can be there, which is the case there, as a change on row iteration has been made using `ResultSet.isLast`, which not garanteed working for all JDBC drivers (btw the way not working with Oracle JDBC driver: [issue #3316](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/pull/3316)).

Either you keep on using release (2.3.4), or you built it from sources, where it's fixed since [#3333](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/pull/3333).